# Why S3 SetContentMD5 is no use in my program

Tags: c++, amazon-s3

I want to use md5 to ensure Aws S3 get what I send, but I set any words into request is OK for S3.

```
void put_object_buf(Aws::String& bucketName, Aws::String& objectName, S3::S3Client& s3_client)
{
    Aws::S3::Model::PutObjectRequest putObjectRequest;
    putObjectRequest.SetBucket(bucketName);

    std::shared_ptr<Aws::IOStream> bigStream = Create5MbStreamForUploadPart("La");

    putObjectRequest.SetBody(bigStream);
    putObjectRequest.SetContentLength(static_cast<long>(putObjectRequest.GetBody()->tellp()));
//    putObjectRequest.SetContentMD5(Aws::Utils::HashingUtils::Base64Encode(Aws::Utils::HashingUtils::CalculateMD5(*putObjectRequest.GetBody())));
    putObjectRequest.SetContentMD5("123");  // still put success
    putObjectRequest.SetKey(objectName);

    Aws::S3::Model::PutObjectOutcome outcome = s3_client.PutObject(putObjectRequest);

    if (!outcome.IsSuccess()) {
        std::cerr << "Error: PutObjectBuffer: " <<
                  outcome.GetError().GetMessage() << std::endl;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "Success: Object '" << objectName << "' uploaded to bucket '" << bucketName << "'." << std::endl;
        std::cout << "outcome crc32: " << outcome.GetResult().GetChecksumCRC32() << std::endl;
        std::cout << "outcome etag: " << outcome.GetResult().GetETag() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

I tried to use real md5 and fake md5 to set into request. But both can work normally.

---

Just now I found an interesting situation.
I found my put request in aws sdk logs is translated as follow:

```
Host: xxx
Accept: */*
amz-sdk-invocation-id: xxx
amz-sdk-request: attempt=1
authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=xxx/20230412/xxx/s3/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=amz-sdk-invocation-id;amz-sdk-request;content-length;content-md5;content-type;host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date, Signature=xxx
content-length: 32
content-md5: Ipcfs07LlrdQhzZWTVN5/Q==
content-type: binary/octet-stream
user-agent: aws-sdk-cpp/1.11.0 Darwin/22.1.0 arm64 Clang/14.0.0
x-amz-content-sha256: UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD
x-amz-date: 20230412T021756Z
Expect: 100-continue
```

This content-md5 is not what I set in request...
Maybe this is a bug in aws C++ sdk?

Comment: Maybe there is some issue in the SDK. Better to also open an issue in their Github repository.

Comment: I think this is a bug...